# xtend2 code generation with ecore meta-model

Tags: code-generation, eclipse-emf-ecore, xtend, xmi, metamodel

I created an ecore-Metamodel, a genmodel and a corresponding model.
Now I want to generate Code from this.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458852/load-emf-model-instance-in-xtend) and wanted to implement it. I get no errors and so on, but how do I bring the CodeGenerator to generate the wanted output in a File like 'test.txt' (taken that example from the referenced question)?

Do I require a workflow file (mwe2) or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only needed to run the application as Java and the code worked. I don't need any workflow or mwe2!

But appearently I still cant create the files like I can with a Generator.
I just can use a simple filewriter.