# Generate code from Metamodel via XTend

Tags: code-generation, emf, xtend

I have an Ecore model in an existing EMF project and want to print the name of all containing classes into a text file via XTend. How do you achieve this? The XTend examples don't show how to use a model and get Information out of it.

Comment: have a look at [Load EMF Model instance in XTend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458852/load-emf-model-instance-in-xtend)

Comment: I don't need an instance of the model. I just need the classes of the metamodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the EClasses of your Meta-Model then you can get them from your Model Package:
`YourEMFModelPackage.eINSTANCE.getEClassifiers()` which returns a `EList<EClassifier>`. Since an `EClass` is an `EClassifier` you get all your EClass implementations `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl`. 
For type-safety concerns you probably check if this List only contains EClasses, since all your `EDataTypes` are also `EClassifier`.

So this should to the Trick:
`EcoreUtil.getObjectsByType(YourEMFModelPackage.eINSTANCE.getEClassifiers(), EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.getEClass())`

or:

`List<EClass> allEClasses = YourEMFModelPackage.eINSTANCE.getEClassifiers().stream().filter(p -> EClass.class.isInstance(p)).map(m -> EClass.class.cast(m)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Update:
If you don't have your Model-Code generated you're still able to do this, you only need to load your Ecore into a Resource:

```
    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("ecore",
            new EcoreResourceFactoryImpl());
    Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(
            URI.createFileURI(
                    "../path/to/your/Ecore.ecore"),
            true);
    EPackage model = (EPackage) resource.getContents().get(0);
```

If you have the `EPackage` then you get your `EClass` like mentioned above

Comment: I have the Ecore model in the model folder. I tried to address it by its package name in the Java file like YourEMFModelPackage but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question implies that it is not possible to work with an Ecore model without generating the code, is this correct?

Comment: Yes you don't actually need Java code from your model to do this, I updated my answer

Comment: The loading into a ressource works. But I can't get the .eINSTANCE of the package. It tells me that it can't be resolved or isn't a field.

Comment: `resource.getContents().get(0)` returns an `EPackage` so you should be able to call `getEClassifiers()` on it

Comment: If this solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Hows does one achieve the same, but with an xcore, rather than ecore, metamodel?